# Unable to start the daemon process...Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, daemon

I keep getting the following error when trying to build my ionic app:

```
* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Gradle\gradle-6.9.1\lib\gradle-launc
her-6.9.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I have tried many of the solutions I've seen online, like creating a _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable and trying to increase the org.gradle.jvmargs value, but I keep getting the same error and don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the memory allowed-  the flag -Xmx2048m.  You're allowing 2048 MB, it's trying to allocate 2090-ish mb.  I'd double it to 4096 at least.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have tried increasing it to 3072, but everytime I do, it runs and then gives me the same error and then when I open gradle.properties again it's reverted back to 2048

Comment: Don't do 3072.  Use a power of 2-  it may not be recognizing that as a valid value.  If your value is being reverted, then you obviously need to find the thing overwriting it and change it there.